# How do you read API documentation in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, documentation

I am trying to read the documentation at https://github.com/mikeal/bent.

I don't know how to read `async request(url[, body=null, headers={}])`.  Specifically, what does the `,` represent?

I have seen an answer to this question before, and I have searched for it, but I could not find it.  Marking this as a duplicate of that would be fantastic.

Comment: https://github.com/mikeal/bent#async-requesturl-bodynull-headers It says the parameters right under it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a step by step for this example:

```
async request(url[, body=null, headers={}])
```

1. The `async` means it's an async function that always returns a promise.
2. `url` is the first argument and is required.
3. The `[, args here ]` means that the arguments inside the brackets are optional.
4. The comma in `[, args here]` means that if you include these arguments, then a comma is required to separate each argument from the previous one.
5. `body=null` means that if you don't pass the `body` argument, the default value is `null`
6. `headers={}` means that if you don't pass the `headers` argument, the default value is an empty object.

So, you can call it like any of these:

```
request(myUrl).then(...).catch(...)
request(myUrl, myBody).then(...).catch(...)
request(myUrl, myBody, myHeaders).then(...).catch(...)
```